# Removing specific Arrays out of multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array, but **not in any guaranteed order**:

```
[ [2,1], [2,2], [2,3], [3,1], [3,2], [4,1], [4,2], [4,3], [4,4], [5,1], [5,2] ]
```

I need to cycle through it, match the ones with the same arr[0] value, and then remove the one with the highest value at arr[1].  It should end up looking like this:

```
[ [2,1], [2,2], [3,1], [4,1], [4,2], [4,3], [5,1] ]
```

I'm not sure exactly how to iterate through this accurately.  Most places I have seen ways to filter complex objects, or remove single values from one-dimensional arrays.

I have only really gotten into using arrays in the last few days.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can we assume it is sorted?

Comment: Not necessarily. The objects get pushed into the array on random user clicks.

Comment: Will all of the pairs be unique (i.e. there won't be more than one `[2,1]`) ?

Comment: What happens if there is only one instance, such as [6,1]?

Comment: Yes. On click of [2,1], [2,2] would be created.  If [2,2] is clicked, [2,3] is created

Comment: why don't you use ++ on every click?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 that can be validated with an if() once I get going the right direction

Comment: @cocco Both are necessary keys. [2,2] is a duplicate of [2,1]. [0] being the type of button, [1] being the "version" of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have two solutions.  `version1` is basic and could use some optimizing while `version2` should be faster with bigger, evenly distributed lists.

If you're only going to have a few items, use one.  It only has a few lines of code, so it won't be a distraction.  If you have a big array and it'll be pretty evenly distributed, then use two.

I actually did a test with the sample data, and `version2` has less iterations than `version1`.  V1 ran 11 times in the outer loop, and 79 times in the inner loop.  V2 ran 11 times in the first outer loop, 4 times in the second one.  The inner loop of the second loop ran 11 times, and the loop inside that ran only 7 times.  So the total iterations of v2 was about 40% of v1.  When I double the items, v2 only uses 30% of the iterations.

`Version2` has a couple of other potential advantages.

- I believe `Array.push` has a higher performance cost than `Array[index] =`.  If that's true, then you know that `newAry` will have a final length of the origianl array's length - the length of the `indicies` array length.  So you can initialize `newAry` with that length, keep a counter variable, and then do something like `newAry[counter++] = someVal`.
- There was some discussion if you wanted to keep a result if there was only one.  If that is the case, it is easy to do a check at the start of the second loop: `if (iVal.length == 1) // add to newAry else do j,k loops`.

**Version 1**

```
function version1(ary) {
    var newAry = [];
    var iVal, jVal;
    for (var i = 0, il = ary.length; i < il; i++) {
        iVal = ary[i];
        for (var j = ary.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (i != j) {
                jVal = ary[j];

                if (iVal[0] == jVal[0] && iVal[1] < jVal[1]) {
                    newAry.push(iVal);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return newAry;
}
```

**Version 2**

```
function version2(ary) {
    var indices = [];
    var values = [];
    var newAry = [];
    var iVal, 
        index,
        highestFound,
        lowFound;

    for (var i = 0, il = ary.length; i < il; i++) {
        var iVal = ary[i];
        if ((index = indices.indexOf(iVal[0])) == -1) {
            indices.push(iVal[0])
            values.push([ iVal[1] ]);
            index++;
        }
        else {
            values[index].push(iVal[1])
        };
    }

    for (var i = 0, il = values.length; i < il; i++) {
        iVal = values[i];
        highestFound = false;
        for (var j = 0, jl = iVal.length; j < jl; j++) {
            if (!highestFound) {
                lowFound = false;

                for (var k = j + 1, kl = iVal.length; k < kl; k++) {
                    if (iVal[j] < iVal[k]) {
                        lowFound = true;
                        newAry.push([indices[i], iVal[j]]);
                        k = kl;
                    }
                }
                if (!lowFound) {
                    highestFound = true;    
                }
            }
            else {
                newAry.push([indices[i], iVal[j]]);
            }
        }
    }

    return newAry;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V5ZJ9/6/)

### [jsFiddle with Counters](http://jsfiddle.net/V5ZJ9/7/)

Comment: What purpose is iIsNotMax serving if it doesn't ever evaluate to true?

Comment: @McPhelpsius Removed that a few minutes ago.

Comment: @McPhelpsius, Version 2 had a bug when the items weren't sorted. I have since fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've given so far, here's the code I came up with:

```
var foo = [
    [2, 1],
    [2, 2],
    [2, 3],
    [3, 1],
    [3, 2],
    [4, 1],
    [4, 2],
    [4, 3],
    [4, 4],
    [5, 1],
    [5, 2]
],
    temp = [];

foo.forEach(function (value, index) {
    if (typeof temp[value[0]] === 'undefined') {
        temp[value[0]] = {
            highestValue: value[1],
            position: index
        };
    } else {
        if (temp[value[0]].highestValue < value[1]) {
            temp[value[0]].highestValue = value[1];
            temp[value[0]].position = index;
        }
    }
});

temp.forEach(function(value, index) {
    delete foo[value.position];
});
```

Do note that if you have in `foo` for instance `[6,1]`, it will be deleted as well.

Answer (score 0):

Making use of the excellent [lodash.js](http://lodash.com/) library:

```
var ary = [ [2,1], [2,2], [2,3], [3,1], [3,2], [4,1], [4,2], [4,3], [4,4], [5,1], [5,2] ];

var results = _(ary)

    // Group by the first value
    .groupBy(function(pair) {
        return pair[0];
    })

    // Turn the groups into arrays
    .map(function(group) {

        // Sort by the second value
        var sorted = _.sortBy(group, function(pair) {
                return pair[1];
            });

        // Keep all but the highest value
        return _.take(sorted, sorted.length-1);
    })

    // Remove the groupings
    .flatten(true)

    // Unwrap the results
    .value();

console.log(results);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dmillz/BhSDT/

I hope that helps!

Comment: I probably won't be venturing into a new js library for this. Currently using jQuery and jQMobile. I won't add another library to the mix